# Play video in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController in which I'm trying to play a video. The video is locally added in my project but when I open the ViewController it shows any error and app crashes, the error is this,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

My code is this,

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[player play];
```

Comment: So, reading the error... what do you think it means? Have you tried debugging this at all?

Comment: Also, make sure that local video is added to the Target Membership. Select **video->Show file Inspector->Target Membership->Enable**

Comment: I have done as u said but not yet working again error is removed but video is not playing just a black blank screen showing. @ImadAli

Comment: @Faheem Add this line `controller.player = player;`

Comment: now working fine please make this ur answer so that I could mark it right. @ImadAli

Comment: @Faheem Added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that local video is added to the Target Membership. Select

> Video->Show file Inspector->Target Membership->Enable.

And add the following line of code:

```
controller.player = player;
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot . @Imad Ali

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
NSURL *vedioURL;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];


  NSString *fullpath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdate.3gp"];
  vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
  AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
  AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
  playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
  playerViewController.player = playVideo;
  playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
  playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
  [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
  [playVideo play];

}


-(NSString *)documentsDirectory{
 NSArray *paths = 
 NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 return documentsDirectory;
}
```

Comment: It is not playing the video. @Mukesh